# NSManagedObject attributes are reset to nil

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, uimanageddocument

I am creating an NSManagedObject subclass (`Group`), set some properties/attributes and then pass it on to a different object (where it is stored in a `strong` property). This object takes some of the `Group` information and sends it to a server over an instance of `GCDAsyncSocket`. The server responds with some information that I then want to store as an attribute of the `Group`. However, by the time the server responds back and `GCDAsyncSocket`'s delegate is called, all of the `Group`'s attributes are set to `nil`.

Since I'm using `UIManagedDocument` for my Core Data implementation, when the auto-save kicks in, I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)" UserInfo=0x1f5c96f0
>   {NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
>       "<Group: 0x1f5aa300> (entity: Group; id: 0x1f5c73b0  ;
>   data: {<entities here, nil values>})" ), NSUnderlyingException=Cannot
>   update object that was never inserted.}

However, I know that the objects are inserted. It did some research and found a lot of problems that were related to using two or more different managed object contexts, but that is not my problem (as the only managed object context I ever get is from the `UIManagedDocument`).

Some code:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) Group *currentGroup;

// ....

- (void)storeGroupOnServer:(Group *)group {
    self.currentGroup = group;
    NSLog("%@", self.currentGroup); // correct value for name attribute
    [self.currentGroup addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

    // do some other things, unrelated to this problem
    // write data to socket
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    // This method is called before the socket returns with response data

    NSLog(@"%@", (Group *)object.name); // incorrect value for name attribute (nil)
    NSLog(@"%@", self.currentGroup); // same as above
}
```

Anybody who has a clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the difference between `self.group` and `self.currentGroup`? Is your context being reset during the fetch? on what thread `self.group.name`  is set?

Comment: I'm sorry, `self.group` should have been `self.currentGroup`, fixed now. The context is not being reset as far as I can tell (memory location remains the same throughout). I thought it was a threading issue, but looking at the stack traces when those calls are made, they all show up under "Thread 1".

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on setCurrentGroup: to see if it is getting modified unexpectedly? Can you compare the objectID of the managed object, before and after, to ensure it is the same object?